# The type 'Windows.Devices.Sensors.Compass' has no constructors defined

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I was following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202974(v=vs.105).aspx) tutorial from MSDN where they show you how to get data from Windows Phone sensors. (in this case, the Compass sensor)

I did not make it far until I ran into a problem: When trying to initialize a new instance of the class Compass itself, I get an error message saying `The type 'Windows.Devices.Sensors.Compass' has no constructors defined`

Here is how the snippet looks:

```
if (compass == null)
    compass = new Compass(); // Error here
```

where `compass` is defined in `public partial class PivotPage : Page`like this

```
Compass compass;
```

I find this very strange since I followed the tutorial from start to finish!

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? It would very much be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't the article talking about other Compass class? It seems to me it talks about `Microsoft.Devices.Sensors.Compass` (look at the root of namespace, "Microsoft" instead "Windows").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows.Devices.Sensors.Compass.GetDefault

Comment: You should add some explanation!! This should be a comment